# Unable to query for AD-Computers under a child domain of a parent domain

Tags: powershell

I've been trying this query to search for AD-Computers under this domain-

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'dc=xx,dc=yy,dc=com' -Filter *
```

But when i fire this command, i get the below error-

```
Get-ADComputer : A referral was returned from the server
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'dc=xx,dc=yy,dc=com' -Filter *
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADReferralException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : A referral was returned from the server,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

But im able to browse/search for AD-Objects on this domain from "Users & Computers mmc."

Kindly advise on this.

Answer (score 0):

All, This is fixed by mentioning the `-server <domaincontroller>` switch

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'dc=xx,dc=yy,dc=com' -Filter * -ResultSetSize 4 -Server dc.domain.com
```